# How to solve OverflowError: mktime argument out of range？

Tags: python, neo4j, buffer-overflow, py2neo

```
begin = time.mktime(time.strptime('1970-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> OverflowError: mktime argument out of range

Comment: What language is this? The tag is for CSS; is this correct?

Comment: This is Python, and I'm going to import Py2neo to build knowledge graphs using the graph database neo4j. However, an error was reported when importing Py2neo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by the Time module in Interchange. According to the post of py2neo project with the same problem on Github, the problem occurred when a user upgraded to 2021.2.0 after using version 2021.1.5, which may be a version problem. You can try to upgrade or downgrade Py2neo to see if the problem can be solved.

https://github.com/py2neo-org/py2neo/issues/916